# Runtime Exception: Unable to instantiate activity component info

Tags: android, crash, instantiation, android-logcat

I have just stripped out the medialytics api from my app because i found it a waste of time and more of a problem than anything else.

Problem is, now my app crashes on start up with the above message in the logcat

Here is the source code for my main activity

```
public abstract class Converter extends Activity {
    private ListView lv1;
    private String lv_arr[] = {"Area", "Density", "Distance", "Energy",
            "Pressure", "Temperature", "Velocity", "Volume", "Weight"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
        adView.requestFreshAd();

        AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] {
            AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR,
                "E83D20734F72FB3108F104ABC0FFC738", 
        } );


        lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.MainList);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, v_arr));
            lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                if ("Area".equals(lv_arr[arg2])){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Converter.this, Area.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }if ("Density".equals(lv_arr[arg2])){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Converter.this,Density.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }if ("Distance".equals(lv_arr[arg2])){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Converter.this,Distance.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }if ("Energy".equals(lv_arr[arg2])){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Converter.this,Energy.class);
                    startActivity(i);     

                }if ("Pressure".equals(lv_arr[arg2])){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Converter.this,Pressure.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }if ("Temperature".equals(lv_arr[arg2])){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Converter.this,Temperature2.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }if ("Velocity".equals(lv_arr[arg2])){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Converter.this,Velocity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }if ("Volume".equals(lv_arr[arg2])){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Converter.this,Volume.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }if ("Weight".equals(lv_arr[arg2])){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Converter.this,Weight.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/app.android.converter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
        myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/MenuText" 
        android:text="Pick a Category to Begin" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_below="@id/ad"
        android:textStyle="bold" /> 
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/MainList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/MenuText" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone spot the problem because for the life of me I cannot.

Comment: The exception in the logcat probably has additional helpful info, like a stack trace.

Comment: You should really read the Java coding style guidelines. Your code is terrible to read.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's very bad to make a `ListView` have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. This will make the `ListView` measure every child.

Secondly, check your `AndroidManifest`. From your code you should have in your manifest several activities.

`"Area", "Density", "Distance", "Energy", "Pressure", "Temperature", "Velocity", "Volume", "Weight"`.

Answer (score 1):

sorry. really really stupid mistake

i had

```
public abstract class
```

instead of

```
public class
```

sorry =(